# Understanding the use of 'src' attribute in Linux routing tables

Tags: ip, iproute

I have a question about a route table in linux which “ip route show” command displays.
I understand what “src” attribute is like based on this link.
http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-saddr-selection.html

My questions are two below.

1. Is there any reasons why people don’t use the “src” attribute for a default gateway or they use it for other routes explicitly as the link below show.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_static_routes_with_ip_commands

2. What is wrong with my understanding?

I assume explicit use of the  “src” attribute can cause an inability to communicate.
I created a network like a diagram below and a route table in “router1" as follows.

[image]

```
default via 192.168.0.2 dev router1-router2 src 192.168.1.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev router1-router2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev router1-host1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1
```

I expected that a “router1” use “192.168.1.1" and couldn’t reach “router2” since the “src” IP address was not in the same LAN.
However it was able to communicate. Why?

Comment: You seem to be saying - implicitly rather than explicitly - that 'router1' and 'router2' are Linux hosts.  If that's true, what makes these two hosts into routers?  Have you enabled IP forwarding and are running daemons in them that exchange routing information with each other?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Yes, 'router1' and 'router2' are Linux hosts.

Partially yes, I have enabled IP forwarding in both of them. But I don't run daemons.

I run a ping from 'router1' to other hosts.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume explicit use of the “src” attribute can cause an inability to communicate.

Perhaps, but not in properly set up networks.

The `src` attribute (called RTA_PREFSRC in Netlink) is a *hint* as to which source IP address to select, for connections made out of this machine. It does not actually *influence* routing, however – if packets match e.g. the 'default' route, they will still use the 'default' route even if the 'src' attribute is different. So the only time it'll break something is if you're trying to communicate with a host that *does not have a route back* to your chosen source address.

(What *would* influence routing is the `from` attribute aka RTA_SRC – adding a 'from' parameter to a route *does* make it match on the source address in addition to the usual destination. However, on Linux this is only implemented for IPv6, not for IPv4.)

> I expected that a “router1” use “192.168.1.1" and couldn’t reach “router2” since the “src” IP address was not in the same LAN. However it was able to communicate. Why?

Because you have *routes* defined all along the way telling systems where to forward packets to “router2” and then back to “192.168.1.1”.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the src attribute what gives the source IP to packets generated in the processes of the host, or is it a combination of this with other factors?

Comment: No, it specifies which source IP would be the *admin preferred* choice out of multiple IPs available. It's in the middle between an explicit bind() done by programs that overrides everything else and the default "source address selection" algorithm that will be done by the OS if nothing else is given.